# Is there a way to change the background color in ezdxf?

Tags: python, ezdxf

I want to change the background color of the photo because it's not clear I tried to change the Figure of `matplotlib` background but it doesn't work

[image: the image]

```py
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import ezdxf
    from ezdxf.addons.drawing import RenderContext, Frontend
    from ezdxf.addons.drawing.matplotlib import MatplotlibBackend
    plt.rcParams["savefig.facecolor"] = 'black'
    plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] = 'black'

    doc = ezdxf.readfile("second.dxf")
    msp = doc.modelspace()
    doc.layers.new(name='MyLines', dxfattribs={'linetype': 'DASHED', 'color': 8})


    auditor = doc.audit()


    if len(auditor.errors) == 0:
       fig = plt.figure()
       ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
       ctx = RenderContext(doc)
       out = MatplotlibBackend(ax)
       Frontend(ctx, out).draw_layout(msp, finalize=True)
       fig.savefig('your.png', dpi=300, facecolor = 'black', edgecolor = 'black')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try overriding MODEL_SPACE_BG_COLOR variable:
`ezdxf.addons.drawing.properties.MODEL_SPACE_BG_COLOR = "#FFFFFF"`

Comment: modifying a global constant is not the way to do this

Answer (score 2):

The `drawing` add-on is still in beta, but you can try this to set the background to white:

```
if len(auditor.errors) == 0:
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
    ctx = RenderContext(doc)

    # --- add this lines ---
    ctx.set_current_layout(msp)
    ctx.current_layout_properties.set_colors(bg='#FFFFFF')
    # --- add this lines ---

    out = MatplotlibBackend(ax)
    Frontend(ctx, out).draw_layout(msp, finalize=True)
    fig.savefig('your.png', dpi=300, facecolor = 'black', edgecolor = 'black')
```

Comment: This has no effect at  0.18.1.    I change transparent to True, then I also get a white background. But then the white lines are not visible any longer:  fig.savefig('your.png', transparent=True, dpi=300)